# NoMethodError - undefined method `reset_password_token' for User:Class:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my `Rails` application, I have a form for admin to create normal users. In `create` `action`, I  am generating a reset password token, and sending a welcome mail to the user, with a link in it to reset his password. This is my code.

```
@user = User.new params[:user]
@user.reset_password_token = User.reset_password_token
@user.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
if @user.save
  UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
  ..
```

This works fine, but I have another app with the same code, but uses `devise 3.2.2` in which I get the this error.

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `reset_password_token' for User:Class:
```

I see that the method has been removed. How can I generate a reset password token and send it to a user?

**Note: I don't want to send the default reset password email**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of digging into `devise`'s source code, I got it to work by doing this.

```
raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(User, :reset_password_token)
@user.reset_password_token = enc
@user.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
if @user.save
  UserMailer.welcome_email(@user, raw).deliver
  ..
```

Use `raw` as the `reset_password_token`

Comment: if it's done close the question by voting for yourself.

Comment: Thankyou sir for your advise, but SO allows me to do that only after 2 days.