# Devise password recovery: undefined method "reset_password_token"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have Devise 3.4.1. Everything works fine except password recovery. I open a page with password recovery, enter my email, click "Submit"... And get this error:

```
undefined method `reset_password_token=' for #<User:0x000000057c3af8>
```

I found the same question here - [NoMethodError - undefined method `reset_password_token' for User:Class:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844896/nomethoderror-undefined-method-reset-password-token-for-userclass) - if I understood it correctly author suggest overriding one of Devise's methods, but I can't understand which method exactly needs to be overridden and most important  - why. Why it just doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: Can you show us the User class ?

Comment: Is there `reset_password_token` in users table in your `schema.rb`. And also look at `db/migrate/yyyymmddhhmmss_devise_create_users.rb`, please.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Mongoid so I added this to `User` model:

```
  field :reset_password_token, type: String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, type: String
```

Now everything works fine. I didn't know I have to add those fields.

Comment: can't this be cached somehow, or it needs to be a field?